# AVPlayer freezes when seeking between two videos of AVComposition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avcomposition

Me and my team have an issue that we can't fix for few weeks now.

When we seek forward between two videos in `AVComposition` - the preview freezes (`AVPlayer` with `AVPlayerLayer` used for playback). It gets stuck on last frame of first video. It doesn’t freeze if it’s a simple playback (not a seek) nor if seek is quick.

Here is screen recording of what's happening:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxk33u3id7eug2i/AVCompositionFreezeScreenRecording.mov?dl=0

It feels like we tried everything, and nothing helps. When adding second video, we ask `AVMutableComposition` for a compatible track, and it returns us existing track, thus we conclude that both `assetTrack`'s are compatible.

All the ranges and duration checked many times.

It fails both when `videoComposition` is set on `playerItem` and when not.

My current theory is even tho `composition` says that existing `compositionTrack` is compatible for second video, we can’t just put second video in it for some reason, maybe the transform is incompatible or I don’t know.
One more note - if we take range of source `videoAssetTrack` with duration that is shorter than `videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration` - then everything works. Maybe some issue with segment time mapping, but anything that we tried with it failed.

I tried to minimize the amount of code needed to demonstrate the issue, so hopefully it will be easy to see what I’m talking about. Just seek slowly from end of video1 to start of video2 and it will get stuck.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6guzplt5mq4zpi/AVCompositionFreezeDemo.zip?dl=0

Thanks very much in advance, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any luck getting this resolved?

Comment: Ultimately we had to use 2 composition tracks and alternate between them

Comment: @OleksiiNezhyborets this is the only workaround that I found as well. Only issue is it unnecessarily increases number of composition tracks that might pose its own limitations in rendering in context of multilayer editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to solve this problem with a trick when creating an AVComposition. Namely, when creating AVComposition, I began to use two instead of one AVCompositionTrack in a checkerboard pattern. This solves the problem of not only different fps for neighboring videos, but also a different transform, if it was applied.

```
let videoTracks = [
    composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!, 
    composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
]

let timeRangeStart: CMTime = .zero
for (index, asset) in assets.enumerated() {
    let videoTrack = videoTracks[index % 2]
    let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)
    do {
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(
            timeRange,
            of: assetTrack,
            at: timeRangeStart
         )
         timeRangeStart = timeRangeStart + timeRange.duration
    } catch {
        logError()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, we ended up with this solution, too. I believe apple does this thing in their sample code, that's were we found it.